# How to create new folder?

Tags: python, mkdir

I want to put output information of my program to a folder. if given folder does not exist, then the program should create a new folder with folder name as given in the program. Is this possible? If yes, please let me know how.

Suppose I have given folder path like `"C:\Program Files\alex"` and `alex` folder doesn't exist then program should create `alex` folder and should put output information in the `alex` folder.

Comment: When you looked in the `os` module, what did you find?  Anything useful?  What code did you try?  Anything?

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You can create a folder with [os.makedirs()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.makedirs#os.makedirs)
and use [os.path.exists()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.exists#os.path.exists) to see if it already exists:

```
newpath = r'C:\Program Files\arbitrary' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
```

If you're trying to make an installer: [Windows Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) does a lot of work for you.

Comment: This will fail because you haven't double-backslashes in the call to os.makedirs.

Comment: It's killing me: newpath = r'C:\Program Files\alex';
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
   os.makedirs(newpath)

Comment: generally speaking pathnames are case-sensitive.

Comment: do `os.path.join('dir','other-dir')` instead of `dir\other-dir` if you want to be compatible with stuff besides windows.

Comment: Could someone explain why os.path.join('dir','other-dir') would be more compatible with other systems? Because of slashes/backslashes?

Comment: Because os.path functions use the local rules of the python installation running the script for path strings.  Using os.path.join in all cases assures that your paths will be formed correctly for the platform the script is being run on.

Comment: this will fail because you don't have Administrator privilege to create a folder in Programs C Directory.

Comment: be watchful since `os.path.exists()` will also evaluate to True, if you have a file with the same name - you'd better use `os.path.isdir()` instead

Answer (score 73):

Have you tried os.mkdir?

You might also try this little code snippet:

```
mypath = ...
if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
   os.makedirs(mypath)
```

makedirs creates multiple levels of directories, if needed.

Answer (score 48):

You probably want [os.makedirs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=mkdirs#os.makedirs) as it will create intermediate directories as well, if needed.

```
import os

#dir is not keyword
def makemydir(whatever):
  try:
    os.makedirs(whatever)
  except OSError:
    pass
  # let exception propagate if we just can't
  # cd into the specified directory
  os.chdir(whatever)
```

Comment: `whatever` is a path?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Yes as string. I would suggest at least logging the error or a print statement so we know there is something wrong.