# python script mkdir plus name from the user

Tags: python

I want to create script that creates folder with name from the user 
Thank you
this is my script

```
#!/bin/python3
import os
folder = str(input())
createFolder = 'mkdir' folder
os.system(createFolder)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274405/how-to-create-new-folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the code, you will notice you receive the following error:

```py
File "/Users/felipefaria/Desktop/test/main.py", line 3
    createFolder = 'mkdir' folder
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Simply formatting your code properly will make it work:

```py
import os

folder = str(input())
createFolder = "mkdir " + folder
os.system(createFolder)
```

Notice the space after `mkdir` so that is is `mkdir {name}` as oppose to `mkdir{name}`.

Comment: Felice Faria thank you very much for the answer . I have one more question  what is the difference  from import subprocess and import os for linux commands

Comment: In essence, [`subprocess` is a newer module that can be used to replace `os.system` and `os.spawn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess): "This module intends to replace several older modules and functions."